# How to call an Oracle function with a Ref Cursor and return the values on Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, oracle, sys-refcursor, ref-cursor

I am trying to call Oracle function which return SYS_REFCURSOR from VB. I was able to retrieve data using stored procedure. Same way I tried to call oracle function but it giving an error.

Appreaciate if anyone can help ? Thanks. I'll provide screen shots if needed.

## Function in DB end

```
PKG BODY

FUNCTION GET_ALLCUST RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS 
  getallcursor SYS_REFCURSOR; 
BEGIN
    OPEN getallcursor FOR SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER; 
    RETURN getallcursor; 
CLOSE getallcursor;
END;

PKG Spec
==============

create or replace PACKAGE GetAllProdPckg AS
   PROCEDURE GetAllProd;
   PROCEDURE get_allprod_viasqldev;
   PROCEDURE get_allcust_viasqldev;
   FUNCTION get_allcust RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;
   function GET_ALLPROD_FROM_DB RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;
   
   END GetAllProdPckg;
```

MY Code =========================================================================

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim rvConn As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
        rvConn = CreateConnection()
        Dim rvCmd As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
        '  Dim OracleRefCursor As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.RefCursor
        Dim ds As DataSet

        Dim oraDataAdapter As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter()


        Try
            rvCmd.Connection = rvConn
            rvConn.Open()

            Dim strSQL As String
            strSQL = "getallprodpckg.get_allcust"
            rvCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            rvCmd.CommandText = strSQL
            MsgBox("")

            Dim qrySerial3 As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("getallpcursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor) With {
            .Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue}


            rvCmd.Parameters.Add(qrySerial3)


            Dim vStr As String
            Dim reader As OracleDataReader = rvCmd.ExecuteReader

            While reader.Read()
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader(0) & reader(1) & reader(2))
                MsgBox(vStr)
            End While


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR OCCURRED" & ex.Message)

        Finally
            rvConn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
```

The Above Code does return a value when i call the Stored Procedure with the cursor object.
The cursor basically returns all data from a table.
But When i Try it on a Function it throws an exception, The code i tried is below.
** ERROR **
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[Exception Thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2FAj.jpg)

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim rvConn As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
        rvConn = CreateConnection()
        Dim rvCmd As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
        '  Dim OracleRefCursor As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.RefCursor
        Dim ds As DataSet

        Dim oraDataAdapter As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter()


        Try
            rvCmd.Connection = rvConn
            rvConn.Open()

            Dim strSQL As String
            strSQL = "select getallprodpckg.get_allcust() from dual"
            rvCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            rvCmd.CommandText = strSQL
            MsgBox("")

            Dim qrySerial2 As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("getallpcursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor) With {
            .Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue}


            rvCmd.Parameters.Add(qrySerial2)


            Dim vStr As String
            Dim reader As OracleDataReader = rvCmd.ExecuteReader

            While reader.Read()
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader(0) & reader(1) & reader(2))
                MsgBox(vStr)
            End While


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR OCCURRED" & ex.Message)

        Finally
            rvConn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

** DB connection class **

```
Public Class Form1 Private Sub TestOracleButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TestOracleButton.Click TestOracleConnection() End Sub

Dim custID As Integer
Dim custID2 As Integer
Dim custName As String
Dim prodID As Integer
Dim prodName As String
Dim prodPrice As Integer
Dim prodAmount As Integer
Dim custAmount As Integer
Dim custStatus As String
Dim prodQuant As Integer

Public Sub TestOracleConnection()
    Dim rvConn As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
    rvConn = CreateConnection()
    Try
        rvConn.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Oracle Connection OK")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        MessageBox.Show("No Oracle Connection established")
    Finally
        rvConn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
Public Function CreateConnection() As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
    Dim rvConn As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection With {
        .ConnectionString = GetConnectionString()
    }
    Return rvConn
End Function
Public Function GetConnectionString() As String
    Dim vConnStr As String
    vConnStr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)"
    vConnStr = vConnStr & "(HOST=feenix-oracle.swin.edu.au)(PORT=1521))"
    vConnStr = vConnStr & "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=dms)));"
    vConnStr = vConnStr & "User Id=S1234564;"
    vConnStr = vConnStr & "Password=******;"
    Return vConnStr
End Function
```

Comment: Actually my friend was trying to help me by creating the question for me. then i tried comment on his question but i could not since i dont have 50 reputation points, so i had to create the same question from my account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the reader from the parameter, not from the command.

So instead of

```
Dim reader As OracleDataReader = rvCmd.ExecuteReader()
```

You need:

```
rvCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
rvCmd.CommandText = "getallprodpckg.get_allcust"

Dim qrySerial3 As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter(
    None, OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)

rvCmd.Parameters.Add(qrySerial3)

rvCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Dim cursor as OracleRefCursor = DirectCast(qrySerial3.Value, OracleRefCursor)

Dim reader As OracleDataReader = cursor.GetDataReader()
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, i am getting error on 'TryCast(qrySerial2.Value, OracleDataReader) saying - 'BC30311: Value of type 'OracleDataReader' cannot be converted to 'OracleRefCursor'.

Comment: OK, that's because you need to specify `rvCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`, not `Text`. Please try the updated code

Comment: Yes that was the issue, thank you very much for your help. i truly appreciate it.

Comment: Could you also please tell me how to get the data into a data grid?

Comment: Just submit a new question clearly indicating which environment (Winforms, WPF, web...) you're on

Comment: @BimsaraAbishekaSenevirathne If the code fixes the issue please accept the answer in the other question so it can benefit others

Comment: Sorry im a newbie to stackoverflow i thought by clicking the up arrow to vote the answer does the job but i got this message 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'

Comment: Is there a different way to do that?

Comment: Oh ok done, my friend told me i have to click the arrow,

Comment: No worries, and welcome to StackOverflow!